# Unable to see Kubernetes option for Windows Container on Windows 10 machine

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-desktop

My windows 10 is [image]

I installed docker edge from the docker website https://hub.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-windows

Initially i tried install Docker, with Windows container setting check box On but the Kubernetes tab did not appear.

Then i Uninstalled and install docker with Linux container option and i could see the Kubernetes tab.

[image]

Can i NOT run Kubernetes for windows containers?

Answer (score 1):

Running kubernetes on Windows 10 is little bit more complicated than it seems. Luckily You have Windows 10 Pro so there are options.

There is an [article](https://learnk8s.io/blog/installing-docker-and-kubernetes-on-windows) which explains everything in detail and also offers different types of workarounds and alternatives.

Hope it helps.